# Trying to run a shell command in Rakefile

Tags: ruby, shell, cucumber, rake

I'm trying to run the following shell command in my RakeFile

```
exclusions = args.version >= "7" ? " -t ~@failing-scenario"  : ""
current_date = DateTime.now.to_s
t.cucumber_opts = "-r Frank/features " + args.selection + (args.idiom == "ipad" ? " -t ~@iphone" : " -t ~@ipad") + exclusions  + " --out ci_artifacts/frank_results"+current_date+".txt --format pretty --format html --out ci_artifacts/frank_results.html --format junit --out ci_artifacts"
sh 'tail -n 3 ci_artifacts/frank_results" + current_date + ".txt >> frank_runtimes.txt'
```

when I run the shell command in `sh`, the file I'm trying to access doesn't exist anymore, but if I try to run the command in `cucumber_opts`, it doesn't recognise the tail command and expects a directory.

Essentially what I am trying to do is save all of Frank's output, and then grab the actual ouput times and save them in a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

`$PATH` and `$PWD` may not be what you expect when running shell commands from other programs. The best way to work around this is to specify the full path for every file you reference, either literally (below example) or using variables to refer to things like the directory where the script is or the user's home directory.

```
sh '/usr/bin/tail -n 3 /path/to/ci_artifacts/frank_results" + current_date + ".txt >> /path/to/frank_runtimes.txt'
```